# Terminal login-credentials to heroku with bash-script?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, heroku, terminal

I'm trying to write a bash script that logs in and creates some stuff on Heroku. Now I have to supply username and password every time. Is it possible to do this automatically, either with some bash-magic or passing variables with the login-function?

PS I'm mostly interested in supplying the e-mail-adress, not the password.

this is what it looks like:

```
 $ heroku auth:login
 Enter your Heroku credentials:
 Email: email@example.com
 Password (typing will be hidden):
 Authentication successful.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at using the Heroku API here instead of the CLI.  For instance Heroku.rb is probably a good start if you're happy with using Ruby.

https://github.com/heroku/heroku.rb

By writing it as a Ruby script you can then wrap it up in bash or whatever.